# Get Max value, Distinct values from Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table like this

```
-----------------------------------
|   Price   |  Brands  |  Colors  |
-----------------------------------
|    300    |     A    |   Red    |
|    200    |     B    |   Red    |
|    500    |     D    |  Green   |
|    800    |     B    |  Orange  |
|    100    |     A    |   Red    |
|    500    |     B    |  Green   |
|    200    |     C    |  Orange  |
|    400    |     D    |   Red    |
```

I want to get **Max (Price)** and **Distinct** values of *Brands and Colors* like this

```
-----------------------------------
|   Price   |  Brands  |  Colors  |
-----------------------------------
|    800    |     A    |   Red    |
|           |     B    |  Green   |
|           |     D    |  Orange  |
|           |     C    |          |
```

What query I should be running to get above result? Is it possible to get above result in single query or I have to run multiple subqueries with joins etc to get this?

Comment: Multiple queries would seem more sensible in this instance as the row results have nothing to do with each other,

Comment: Where is your sql query? What did you already try for yourself?

Comment: Don't you mean Distinct values of Brands and Distinct values Colors?

Comment: @jarlh yes I mean Distinct Values for both

Comment: @AlexanderBalzer I actually tried many queries and could not get required result. I thought it would be messy if I post all those useless queries here. But Let me put them. Just wanted to keep clean to understand

Comment: @Strawberry I think you are right. Let me edit my question and put some example and please do check if they are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible to get that all in 1 query, but it isn't good practice since that data doesn't represent anything. MySQL is a *Relational* DataBase Management System (*R*DBMS) so the data is output has to have a relation together.

In this case, you want the max(price), distinct(brands) and distinct(colors), with no relations between them and you should make 3 different calls

Comment: OK yup you are right. They don't have any relation and thus I need to make three different subqueries and join them. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow one of us is missing something here... and I have no clues if it's you or me. If they aren't related in any way, how and why are you gonna join them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables and `union all`:

```
select max(price) as price, max(brand) as brand, max(color) as color
from (select 1 as rn, max(price), NULL as brand, NULL as color from t
     ) union all
     (select (@rnb := @rnb + 1), NULL, brand, NULL
      from t cross join (select @rnb := 0) params
      group by brand
     ) union all
     (select (@rnc := @rnc + 1), NULL, NULL, color
      from t cross join (select @rnc := 0) params
      group by brand
     )
    ) t
group by rn
order by rn;
```

The key idea is that you need a way to identify what is on each row.  This information is not in the original data.  You can generate a "row number" using variables.  In this case, `union all` is preferable to a `join`, because MySQL doesn't support `full outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         MAX(Price), Brands, Colors
  FROM YOU_TABLE_NAME ;
```

PS:- using small letters in the fields name will be more standard for the database .

Comment: No, your query will not match the OPs requirement.